# mantener la misma posicion de un recyclerView al volver atras

Tags: java, android

Tengo una pregunta como puedo regresar a la misma posición de mi recyclerView, dado que al regresar de otra actividad me manda al inicio y quisiera mantener la misma posición en el que la deje.
cabe resaltar que estoy usando un GridLayout y que dicho recycler se encuentra dentro de un fragmento, es posible regresar a la misma posición de la ultima vista?
gracias.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new Adapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Y si volteas el dispositivo con el recycleview en un elemento, también regresa al inicio?

Comment: Me parece que es el mismo problema, ya que estando en otra actividad puede estar girando nuevamente el dispositivo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si cargas otra actividad, puedes guardar la posición cuando se ejecuta el método `onPause()` de la actividad inicial.

Agrega 2 métodos en tu adapter, para obtener y almacenar la posicion:

```
    public int getSelectedPosition() {
        return selectedPosition;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition) {
        this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    }
```

para obtener la posición lo puedes realizar con `.getSelectedPosition()` de tu Adapter.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (miAdapter != null) {
            selectedPosition = miAdapter.getSelectedPosition();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Al regresar simplemente mueve a ala posición de tu adapter.

```
miAdapter.setSelectedPosition(selectedPosition);
```

#### Si quieres conservar la posición cuando gira tu aplicación puedes guardar la posición a traves de `onSaveInstanceState()` por ejemplo:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt("miPosicion", selectedPosition);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

y dentro de `onCreate()` recupera la posición:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...
selectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("miPosicion");
...
..
```

Mueve a la posición guardada tu Adapter:

```
miAdapter.setSelectedPosition(selectedPosition);
```